# Add a property to a dynamic object where the name of the property will only be known at runtime

Tags: silverlight, gridview, dynamic

I have looked into the documentation for dynamic objects but i wasn't able to find a solution
to my current problem.

I have this code :

```
dynamic sampleObject = new ExpandoObject();

string columnName = checkBox.Content.ToString();

sampleObject.columName = myObservableCollection;
```

Now, the name of my added property will be columnName, but I would like it to be the content of my checkbox.

How should I implement that ?

Thanks

Comment: This seems like a misuse of dynamic. A simple Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection> would do the same thing better for your specific example (possibly with a convertor if you are binding to a data grid). What is the overall aim you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have an object with several static properties (name,age,etc ) that I bind to a radgridview (telerik grid). But I also need to add some dynamic properties chosen from a list of checkboxes by the user. Those properties are dynamic because the user can add or remove the properties in another part of the program. (I hope my explanation was clear enough)

Comment: Ok, but then they are only dynamic because you wanted to bind all properties automatically (i.e. let the grid do all the work). Why not add the grid columns and bindings programatically instead? It will give you more flexibility over what you display/edit in the grid.

Comment: I add the column programmaticaly already, but my problem is adding the "dynamic" properties to my object. It seems I need to use/test the dictionary you mentionned. Thanks :)

Comment: I moved this to an answer so I could add some sample code for the converter. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary of named values instead of dynamic properties.

You can use a Dictionary converter to bind to specific entries in the dictionary (using the converter parameter value as the key). [Code below from this link](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/51864.aspx)

```
public class DictionaryItemConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dict = value as Dictionary<string, string>;
        if (dict != null)
        {
            return dict[parameter as string];
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Where you add columns to the grid via code you will need to create a binding with the correct converter and name converter parameter.